# Freezing funds with positive balance

Tags: wills, banking, freedom-of-information

My spouse's son is on an account with his stepmother. Both were put on the account at different times by his dad. Unfortunately his dad passed away recently. The money in the account was to be split 50/50. The stepmother started withdrawing money immediately after her husband's death. The son inquired about the balance. It was considerably lower than expected. Now the bank froze all assets. Question: shouldn't he still he allowed to withdraw at will? Him and his stepmother are both legal owners of the account. Also, we don't know of any will.

Comment: Which country or state is involved? The law isn't uniform on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Banks often freeze accounts when ownership appears to be disputed. While being a co-signer can provide authority to withdraw funds from an account, it only sometimes implies ownership of all of the funds contained in it that can be withdrawn at will.